# How to check in every row in a column if it contains a substring

Tags: r, grepl

Let's say I have a column 'name' in the dataframe `df`:

```
apple
apple123
app
be
aple
```

and, I want to check if every row in the `name` column contains the word `apple`.
The way I did it was to use `grepl`, `grepl('apple',df$name)`, I was hoping it would return `'TRUE','TRUE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE'`, however, it returned 5 `'FALSE'` instead.

Did I do anything wrong here, if not `grep`l, what function should I use?

Comment: You'll need to provide output of `dput(df)`. When I do `dat <- data.frame(name=c("apple", "apple123", "app", "be", "aple")) ; grepl("apple", dat$name)` I get `[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE`

Comment: Thank you hrbrmstr! grepl() does its job, my real life case has something to do with encoding, see my comment below, I guess that's where things went wrong.

Answer (score 6):

I get it running fine

```
dat <- c('apple', 'apple123', 'app', 'be', 'aple')
grepl('apple', dat)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
dat[grepl('apple', dat)]
[1] "apple"    "apple123"
```

This is exactly the same with a data.frame

```
dat <- data.frame(v=c('apple', 'apple123', 'app', 'be', 'aple'))
grepl('apple', dat$v)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

which is the same if you do

```
with(dat, grepl('apple', v))
```

Comment: Thank you Paulo. Yes, grepl works fine with English, but seems that it does not work with Japanese. I faked the example in the question just to keep it simple, my real life case is I was trying to use grepl() to determine if each row in my dataframe contains "ハローワーク". I guess this is an encoding issue rather than use of grepl().

Comment: @user3569522 Japanese characters not always express words but short ideas or phrases right? This must be harder, I think.